# r shiny data table sometimes does not display

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I encountered a weird situation that made me confused and searched for a while but seems no same issues as mine with data table package.

I simply used the basic default data table in my shiny app, see example:

**Server.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(DT)
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$expense_table_check<-renderDataTable({
   iris
 })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
mainPanel(
      navlistPanel(
       tabPanel("DT",h1("DT"),
       dataTableOutput("expense_table_check"))
   )
  )
 ) 
)
```

Sometimes the above works fine but sometimes not. I tried replacing `dataTableOutput("expense_table_check")` with 
`dataTableOutput('expense_table_check')` and then it works sometimes, but sometime not.

I also tried replacing the output name `expense_table_check` with `expense_table_check2`. But still cannot solve the issue. Any suggestion or comment is appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also what version of `DT` nad `shiny` package are you using? OS too? Everything is working fine at my end

Comment: Browser : IE, chrome, Safari;  OS : Mac and windows, DT version: 0.1, shiny version: 0.13.2

Comment: The app that you provided works fine for me, I also have the same versions of the packages. Are you doing anything else after?

Comment: It's sometime works very fine for me but sometimes it just not display the table . I put apps on 2 different shiny-servers and the issues are the same.

Comment: Whenever it happens again, right-click on the page and select `inspect` and see what the page consists of.

Comment: I checked the console in the "inspect " in google chrome and seems no issue but it just not display.  May it is masked sometimes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120415/discussion-between-samotht-and-pork-chop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the issues after revising the code as following and now it works well all the time; just add `DT::` in front of datatable:

**Server.R**

```
 library(shiny)
 library(DT)
 shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 output$expense_table_check <- DT::renderDataTable({
   iris
 })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
mainPanel(
      navlistPanel(
       tabPanel("DT",h1("DT"),
       DT::dataTableOutput("expense_table_check"))
   )
  )
 ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This just helped me immensely. Is there any reason why this would be the case, though? Why do you have call the `DT` namespace when the package is already loaded and it works (sometimes)?

Comment: Because ````renderDataTable```` is also a function in ````shiny````, so there's a conflict

Comment: I've got the same issue, but I am using `renderDT` in my code so I guess this is not the full explaination of the root cause of the issue.